# Changing the encoding of HTML that is converted to PDFs, based on users choice of encoding type

Tags: c#, pdf, character-encoding

I am creating a web application that allows users to input various amounts of data that uses a generic HTML template that can be used to export the data as a PDF. There are a few configurations that the user can set prior to exporting the data. One of the configurations I am trying to add is a way for users to change the encoding. By default, the encoding is "utf-8." However, I would like to add functionality to allow a user to select utf-16 as an option for special characters.

I am not sure how I would achieve this.

I have tried manually setting the charset in the "head" tag to be a variable thats value is set by a user selecting a value in a drop down (utf-8 or utf-16). However, it seems like it is not changing and defaulting it to utf-8.

Below is what I tried:

```
var encoding = "UTF-16";
var html = "<!DOCTYPE html><head><meta charset=\"" + encoding + "\"></meta><style>" + styles + "</style></head><body>##CONTENT##</body></html>";
```

Comment: You have html where special characters have to be escaped.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references  You can use following to do the escaping : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure what you mean. If I do it without the meta tag: "<!DOCTYPE html><head><style>" + styles + "</style></head><body>##CONTENT##</body></html>" it works perfectly fine. But when I add the meta tag, it doesn't change the template and defaults to UTF-8

Comment: You need to use a font that supports the characters as well as the language. You need to read note 'b' which is on the DTD column of my link above.